# CaptureCameraDialog returns OK but does not save (Motorola ES400)

Tags: windows-mobile, camera, windows-ce, pocketpc, windows-mobile-6

Ok it seems like everyone in the world has issues with CaptureCameraDialog.

In my case the result is OK, but when taking the photo there is a MessageBox that says "Error" that appears and disappears in the blink of an eye, then returns to my app (so I don't have time to actually read the error).

It has not saved the file.
It does not throw an error to my application.

There is also another issue which is exactly the same as the issue talked about here (yet none of the fixes work for me).
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-4025602.php

Does anyone know how to get the "error message" that the dialogue box displays for an instant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of hair pulling it seems that the program I was using always had an open connection to SQLCompact. The code was from a third party and din't have a Close() or Dispose() so this was the problem.

To get round it I just did a Process.Start on a tiny application I wrote that literally runs, takes a picture, saves it to disk, then unloads. In the meantime my app started a timer to watch a directory for the photo.

This was a pretty terrible solution, but it works and I was out of time, so had to be done!